# Selenium Image element id changes after each execution- How to click on the image

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on an image, but after each execution or when new swssion of the application opened the "id" assigned to that image changes as mentioned below. Please help me with this.

```html
<img class="x-form-trigger x-form-arrow-trigger" id="ext-gen307" src="/slm/js-lib/ext/2.2/resources/images/default/s.gif" complete="complete"/>
```

```html
<img class="x-form-trigger x-form-arrow-trigger" id="ext-gen306" src="/slm/js-lib/ext/2.2/resources/images/default/s.gif" complete="complete"/>
```

```html
<img class="x-form-trigger x-form-arrow-trigger" id="ext-gen308" src="/slm/js-lib/ext/2.2/resources/images/default/s.gif" complete="complete"/>
```

Comment: try locating element using dynamic xpath or css locator

Answer (score 1):

I would personally prefer to use the `id`, `name` or `title` attribute to match.  Since the image you want has an `id`, you can match on that.

The ID however, appears to be dynamic so you need to account for this.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[id^='ext-gen']"))
```

This, in english means `"Find me an <img> that has an id="" attribute that *starts with* "ext-gen"`

You can match on the `src`, but personally you should prefer other attributes that are less-likely to change, such as the ID.

See [this page](http://ddavison.io/css/2014/02/18/effective-css-selectors.html) for a reference on CSS selectors for Selenium.

Comment: There is one more image in the webpage, when i tried the code above that image is getting clicked but not the right image getting clicked.

Comment: code of other image in webpage :  <img id="ext-gen266" class="x-form-trigger administratable-workspaces-picker-trigger " src="/slm/js-lib/ext/2.2/resources/images/default/s.gif"></img>

Comment: then you need to do a higher specificity.  Could you share more HTML that surrounds the `<img>`?  Can't get much further without it.

Comment: <div id="ext-comp-1025" class="x-layer x-editor x-small-editor x-grid-editor" style="position: absolute; z-index: 11000; visibility: visible; left: 735px; top: 2px; overflow: auto; width: 74px;">

    <div id="ext-gen356" class="x-form-field-wrap x-trigger-wrap-focus" style="width: 68px; visibility: visible;">
        <input id="ext-comp-1024" class=" x-form-text x-form-field rally-combobox x-form-focus" type="text" name="ext-comp-1024" autocomplete="off" size="24" style="width: 55px;" title=""></input>

Comment: <img id="ext-gen357" class="x-form-trigger x-form-arrow-trigger " src="/slm/js-lib/ext/2.2/resources/images/default/s.gif"></img>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="ext-gen47" class="x-grid3-resize-marker"></div>
    <div id="ext-gen48" class="x-grid3-resize-proxy"></div>

Answer (score 0):

Try this, This would work perfect.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[src*='s.gif']"))
```

please update incase this is not working

Comment: There is one more image in the webpage, when i tried the code above that image is getting clicked but not the right image getting clicked. Code of that image :  <img id="ext-gen266" class="x-form-trigger administratable-workspaces-picker-trigger " src="/slm/js-lib/ext/2.2/resources/images/default/s.gif"></img>

Comment: Hi @ChetanKumarT can you please provide the webpage, i'll work on it and update you

Comment: Hi its Rally application- which is user for agile project maintainance.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather go with `src` attribute to identify the image as this would change rarely. Even if it changes, then it makes sense that the test is failing.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@src='/slm/js-lib/ext/2.2/resources/images/default/s.gif']"))
```

**Or**

I would use a combination of a part of `id` along with `src`

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@src='/slm/js-lib/ext/2.2/resources/images/default/s.gif'][contains(@id,'ext-gen')]"))
```

Comment: Even for this solution, one more image in the webpage is getting selected. Please help.

Comment: Did you try the second solution?

Comment: yes brother i tried, same result. The other image is situated first than the image to be clicked in the webpage. So i think the other image is getting clicked.

Comment: Do you know which element has to be clicked? If Yes, then try this to click the second image: `driver.findElements(By.xpath("//img[@src='/slm/js-lib/ext/2.2/resources/images/default/s.gif'][contains(@id,'ext-gen')]"))[1]`

Comment: Getting the below error when i tried the above soultion. Error : "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to List<WebElement>"

Comment: Did you call the click method? `driver.findElements(By.xpath("//img[@src='/slm/js-lib/ext/2.2/resources/images/‌​default/s.gif'][contains(@id,'ext-gen')]"))[1].click();`

Comment: browser.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@src='/slm/js-lib/ext/2.2/resources/images/default/s.gif']"))[1].click();

Comment: Please use `findElements` insetad `findElement` as I had told in my comments

Comment: Getting same error after using 'FindElements' also.

Comment: I could give exact solution if you could send me the html file.